# rm -rf destroyed directories of the files set to be deleted (multiple arguments)

Tags: bash, scripting, rm, testing, deleted-files

In a testing environment I executed:

```
rm -rf /var/www/html/${domain} /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain} /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${domain}
```

The result was that `html`, `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories were deleted with all their content.

What's wrong with that phrasing? Given I gave full paths, I miss what may cause that, I assume it has nothing to do with the recursivness of `-r`.

Comment: If the value of `domain` was empty or undefined, you just ran, e.g., `rm -rf /var/www/html`. I suspect that is the source of your problem.  Are you testing that `domain` has a non-null value before trying to use it?

Comment: Ah **** you are right, it is part of a script and I copy just that without variable declaration, instead running the entire script... Is there a way to defend from this with an argument in case it happens agian? (Didn't find something in `man rm` or I missed one).

Comment: sometimes, you just have to be careful. But if you aren't sure, echo(ing) the statement is a quick visual verification (if executing on the cli).

Comment: Never run an rm command using a variable without doing either an echo of it to very variables are OK either testing variable values before (even inside a script of course)  && forget existance of  copy/paste while running a rm command  from terminal  ....  always full type the command ... when you loose important data once..... you act like this forever :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the value of domain was empty or undefined, you just ran, e.g., `rm -rf /var/www/html`.

You can check explicitly that `domain` is defined:

```
if [ -z "$domain" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: domain is undefined" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Also, using `set -u` in your script can prevent this sort of problem.  This causes the use of an undefined variable to result in an error:

```
$ set -u
$ echo $undefined_variable
bash: undefined_variable: unbound variable
```

Comment: There's also the option of the cheapish but less verbose and invasive protection `domain=${domain:-emptyvar}`